# Can't install R package: "non-zero exit status" (unless sudo)

Tags: r, ubuntu, anaconda

Strange behavior: prior to now, I've been able to install R packages using R studio, etc., specifically using `install.packages("<package name>")`. Now, unless I run R using `sudo` directly in a terminal window, I can't install packages without receiving the following traceback:

```
> install.packages("mlbench")
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
trying URL 'https://mirrors.sorengard.com/cran/src/contrib/mlbench_2.1-1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 920768 bytes (899 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 899 KB

* installing *source* package ‘mlbench’ ...
** package ‘mlbench’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
/home/alex/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc -I/home/alex/anaconda3/lib/R/include -DNDEBUG   -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -I/home/alex/anaconda3/include   -fpic  -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -pipe -I/home/alex/anaconda3/include  -c waveform.c -o waveform.o
make: /home/alex/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc: Command not found
/home/alex/anaconda3/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:160: recipe for target 'waveform.o' failed
make: *** [waveform.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘mlbench’
* removing ‘/home/alex/anaconda3/lib/R/library/mlbench’
* restoring previous ‘/home/alex/anaconda3/lib/R/library/mlbench’

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/RtmpRBWDWi/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
Warning message:
In install.packages("mlbench") :
  installation of package ‘mlbench’ had non-zero exit status
```

**This is happening for quite a few that I have tried, but `mlbench` is the one that I am most concerned with right now.**

Any help is much appreciated.

R (with anaconda)
Kubuntu 17.10 (Artful)

Comment: A [casual search](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/issues/770) suggests that the use of `x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc` in an R environment is not well supported. Is there a reason you are using that specific compiler? (Is that the default for kubuntu?)

Comment: It does appear to be the default for Kubuntu. Trying the tip passed on that link about how to resolve this. Thanks for your Google-Fu.

Comment: @r2evans if you post that as an answer I will gladly accept it.

Comment: No "anything fu" in that one, I'd never thought about using a conda-based gcc on a linux box, so it was casual, shallow, and likely missing a lot. Quite the contrary, I have no doubt that there's a lot I'm missing there. However, in that link was commentary from Dirk, a person who is very in-touch with C-compiled in and around R, with extra time in debian (ubuntu ancestor), so thought it was shallow, I have reason to not dive deeper.

Comment: Regardless- you have my thanks. Quite the headscratcher for a bit.

Answer (score 0):

As posted by @r2evans in the comments, this [link](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/issues/770) provides the tip that worked for me.

Because I am using anaconda to manage my R environment, this is what fixed the issue I was having: `conda install gxx_linux-64`.

**Also:**

If you are seeing similar errors but with a traceback line similar to `make: /home/alex/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gfortran: Command not found...`, use a terminal to run the same line as above, but specifying `gfortran` instead of `gcc`: `conda install gfortran_linux-64`.